# Preparing a query as String using JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have the following query and params. I dont want to execute the `query(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject)` but instead pass this query with params as string to another method. How can I assign this params to prepared statement and save the query as a string?

```
final String QUERY = "select * " 
+  "from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY " 
+ "where INSURANCE_ID = ? and " 
+ "SYS_CD = ? and " 
+ "ACCT_TYPE in (?)";

Object[] params = new Object[] { 
    request.getInsuranceId(),
    request.getSystemId(),
    AcctNameBuilder.toString()
};
```

Comment: Short answer you can't. If you do it it is not longer a prepared Statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this because replacing `?` in a prepared statements with actual values in most cases will force database to re-process and re-plan the SQL query. It's really wasteful, if you already have a prepared statement so use it.

You could however define a shared `PreparedStatementCreator` object and pass it to [`JdbcTemplate#query(PreparedStatementCreator psc, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at String.format.

```
String.format("Hello %s, %d", "world", 50);
```

Would return "Hello world 50".

Format specifiers:

%s - insert a string

%d - insert a signed integer (decimal)

%f - insert a real number as standard notation

An other example:

```
String.format("The {0} is repeated again: {0}", "word");
```

Return: "The word is repeated again: word"